# How to compare json parsed time with ruby object time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some controller tests and I want to check the response values.  I am unable to compare `JSON.parse(...["start_time"])` with `foo.start_time` with the following stack trace:

```
   expected: 2016-09-17 10:50:00.000000000 +0000
        got: "2016-09-17T10:50:00.000Z"
```

I tried a bunch of parsing techniques but they either return different formats, or do not return accurate values.  Is there a simple way to get these values in to the same format to compare equality?

Comment: Read "[mcve]". Please add a small JSON snippet that shows the string you're parsing including the Date, along with the code where you compare the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to compare two different data types.  The parsed JSON is a string.  The foo.start_time attribute is a Ruby datetime.

Do the following:

```
(JSON.parse(...["start_time"])).to_datetime
```

That will convert the string into a datetime, which can then be compared to foo.start_time.